# How to do update in nested map DynamoDb

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a DDB table named cart and my order column is in the following format

```
"order": {
    "PRD_SHOES_048": {
      "price": "40.99",
      "productId": "PRD_SHOES_048",
      "quantity": "1"
    }
  }
```

When I try to add new items to the order the existing value is getting updated and only new value will be there in the table. I need the column to be looking something like this

```
"order": {
    "PRD_SHOES_048": {
      "price": "40.99",
      "productId": "PRD_SHOES_048",
      "quantity": "1"
    },
 "PRD_TOP_047": {
      "price": "40.99",
      "productId": "PRD_TOP_047",
      "quantity": "1"
    }
  }
```

I'm using lambda function written in node js.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var table = "e_cart";var input = event;

var params = {
 TableName : table,
 Item: input
 };
 console.log("Params"+JSON.stringify(params));
    console.log("Adding a new item..."); 

docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
     if (err) {
            callback(null, {
                "statusCode": 400,
                "message": JSON.stringify(err.message)
            });

        } else {
        callback(null, {"statusCode": 200,"message": "Success","cartId": ts});
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

You should add an `items` attribute to your JSON. The way it is right now it's really hard to track all the items. Your order object should look like this:

```
{
    "order": {
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "PRD_SHOES_048",
                "price": "40.99",
                "productId": "PRD_SHOES_048",
                "quantity": "1"
            },
            {
                "id": "PRD_TOP_047",
                "price": "40.99",
                "productId": "PRD_TOP_047",
                "quantity": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now, you can easily add a new item to your order. Just fetch the order and push the new item like this:

```
order.items.push(myNewItem)
// save in DynamoDB...
```